# How to get the Pin-password in Android.?

Tags: java, android

i am try to compare the Stored-password and Salted Password for the Experiment. Now i have a Stored Password and Salted-password., **Stored-password having 72-byte and Salted-password having 18-bytes** only, but i facing problem on comparison, how can i compare the both of them..
Here my Code :

```
     RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
     final byte[] stored = new byte[(int) raf.length()]; // in File : "9F3F4E45C0B58B410333D5CB45EB94B708285E80E77F85E1545B9CED25044EAF9158EADB";
     String saltedPw="2013527f8d155ecf0";

     byte[] saltedPassword=saltedPw.getBytes();
     byte[] sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(saltedPassword);
     byte[] md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(saltedPassword);
     byte[] hashed=(toHex(sha1)+toHex(md5)).getBytes();
     Arrays.equals(hashed, stored);    // its mismatching here
```

i compared both of them but its mismatching. what is the problem on that.. how can i get the Pin-number..  Anyone help me...

Thanks in Advance.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using 'Hash' of stored password.

Comment: thanks for your Reply.. ok dude.. how can i do the hash for stored password.. is (sha1 or md5)..

Comment: do it in the same way you are doing for salted password. For your example it's the concatenation of sha1 and mdf.

Comment: i have a one question, stored password already hashed na..then why we need to do hash again..

Comment: If it is, then you don't need to. You just need to know with which method the hash has been calculated and apply the same for salted password.

Comment: because stored password come from android device., its already hashed na

Comment: String m_temp_saltedPw="2013527f8d155ecf0";
byte[] saltedPassword=m_temp_saltedPw.getBytes();
byte[] m_temp_storepw=m_temp_storedPw.getBytes();
byte[] sha1_storedpw=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(m_temp_storepw);
byte[] md5_stoedps=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(m_temp_storepw);
byte[] hashed_storedpw=(toHex(sha1_storedpw)+toHex(md5_stoedps)).getBytes(); Arrays.equals(hashed, hashed_storedpw);